# How can I split a integer array to n integer array dynamically?

Tags: java, arrays

Here I have integer array contains `81` values so that I need to store `9` values per array total I need to get 9 arrays. Eg: `array1` from `1 to 9` and `array2` from `10 to 18` and `array3` from `19 to 27` like that. Can anybody help me how to get this values?

```
public class demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int num = 81;
       int numArray = num / 9;
        int[] input = new int[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            input[i] = i + 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(input[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

How to get desired result?

Comment: what are you trying to display?? and you are not even using the numArray so why is it created , Your question is not very clear

Comment: Use either System.arraycopy or one of the methods of the Arrays class.

Comment: @Mohit_Bhasi,i need to create 9 arrays ,each array contains 9 values.

Comment: @khanam thanks for the clarification , surely will provide an answer:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`System#arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-):

```
int[] first_part = new int[27];
int[] second_part = new int[27];
int[] third_part = new int[27];

System.arraycopy(input, 0, first_part, 0, 27);
System.arraycopy(input, 27, second_part, 0, 27);
...
```

I've just noticed that you want 9 parts, you can easily put this in a loop and use `arraycopy`.

Comment: Maroun, is it possible to create arrays dynamically based on given input eg:num=81 so that i can create 9 array.

Comment: Yes, using a loop. Think about `ArrayList` of arrays or something like that.

Comment: Maroun, Could you please Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 85;
    int limit = 5;
    int index = 0;
    int extra = 0;
    int finalArrayIndex = 0;
    int[] innerArray = null;
    int[] input = new int[num];
    boolean isEnd = false;

    if (num % limit > 0) {
        extra = 1;
    }

    int[][] finalArray = new int[(num / limit) + extra][limit];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i = i + (limit)) {

        innerArray = new int[limit];
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {

            innerArray[j] = input[index++];
            if (index >= input.length) {
                isEnd = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        finalArray[finalArrayIndex++] = innerArray;

        if (isEnd) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // just for test
    for (int k = 0; k < finalArray.length; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < finalArray[k].length; l++) {
            System.out.println("finalArray[" + k + "]" + "[" + l + "] : "
                    + finalArray[k][l]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is dynamic solution, you can change value of `num` and `limit` variables. I hope this will help you :)
Java Fiddle link : http://ideone.com/jI8IOb

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use [subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

You can follow these steps.

1. Store all 81 values in a `List` (`ArrayList`)
2. Then create 9 sub `List` from that using `subList()`
3. You can convert `List` to `array`.

   ```
   List<Integer> fullList=new ArrayList<>();        
   List<Integer> list1=fullList.subList(0,8); // first 9 elements
   Integer[] bar = list1.toArray(new Integer[list1.size()]);
   ```

Comment: Ruchira Gayan Ranawee,without using any builtin function,is it not possible?

Comment: @khanam No. you don't need to use build in methods. you can write a code to do it. I suggest this since it is less to do.

Comment: @Could you please help me to get my desired output.

Comment: @khanam can you please post what you want to do and so far what you have tried? you can reach me in skype or using a e-mail since you can't use chat in stackOverFlow yet.

Comment: Ruchira Gayan Ranaweera,check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602719/how-to-print-non-repeated-numbers-from-integer-array-using-java?noredirect=1#comment43628402_27602719