# how to print non repeated numbers from integer array using java and without using predefined api's?

Tags: java, arrays

here i have code to print non repeated numbers from given array.I know the concept but while applying to logic i'm unable to get exact output.

```
public class NumberFinder {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    int[] input = {10, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 23, 34, 12};
    int[] output = new int[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < input.length; j++) {
            if (input[i] == input[j]) {
                count++;
            } else {
                output[j - 1] = input[i];
                System.out.println(input[j]);
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

from the above array i need to print non repeated values are as follows:10,4,5,1,23,34,12.
Could anybody guide me.Your help will be appreciated.

Edit - Almas - This question is not duplicate of what Suresh has marked for.

Here's what you could do:
You could use Map and maintain a count of times its repeating like:

```
int[] input = new int[] { 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10 };
    boolean found;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                continue;
            if (input[i] == input[j]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println(input[i]);
        }
    }
```

You can try also this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] input = { 3,10,7, 10, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 23, 34, 5, 12, 4, 63,63,111 };

    int duplicateNumber[] = new int[input.length];
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        boolean alreadyDuplicated = false;
        for (int l = 0; l < k; l++)
        {
            if (input[i] == input[duplicateNumber[l]])
            {
                alreadyDuplicated = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!alreadyDuplicated)
        {
            boolean insertFirst = false;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++)
            {
                if (input[i] == input[j])
                {
                    if (insertFirst == false)
                    {
                        duplicateNumber[k++] = i;
                        insertFirst = true;
                    }
                    duplicateNumber[k++] = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int[] output = new int[input.length - k];
    int out = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        boolean duplicatedFound = false;
        for(int j = 0;j<k;j++)
        {
            if(input[i] == input[duplicateNumber[j]])
            {
                duplicatedFound = true;
            }
        }
        if(!duplicatedFound)
        {
            output[out++] = input[i];
        }
    }
    for (int l = 0; l < output.length; l++)
    {
        System.out.println(output[l]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SummerCode,that is not the same question,from given provided link (Kick Buttowski answers)output as:1 3 7 8 9 10 but from my point of question output should be 3 8 10

Comment: without using list,any builtin functions.can i get the output.

Comment: sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ,my question is not duplicate,

Comment: @almasshaikh,can you edit above code if possible.

Comment: @almasshaikh,without using any predefined java api's ,need to get output.

Comment: you should be clear when asking @khanam

Comment: ok @almasshaikh,sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @khanam I updated for you.

Comment: @almasshaikh,there is no option to voteup or accept your answer.

Comment: No problem. I would be glad if you say it helped you...

Comment: @khanam see my code above if it's working for you :)